# Getting city boundaries from openstreetmap

Tags: php, openstreetmap

I'm developing a website and I need to get all the boundaries of an area given depending on the user input.
For example, the user want to know the boundaries of a city named x. How should I get it from openstreetmap? I've heard of xapi and osmosis but couldnt find any examples anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try a Google search? http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/

Comment: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8117/getting-city-border-from-osm-data

Comment: I just want to get all the lat long of the city in one query. I think nominatim has that capability but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I took a stab at doing this with JavaScript here: 
https://github.com/pgkelley4/city-boundaries-google-maps

Basically it comes down to finding the [relation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) that OpenStreetMap stores the city boundaries as.

I used something like the following query to get the area:

```
area[name="Seattle"]["is_in:state_code"="WA"];foreach(out;);
```

Or if that doesn't find anything, going through the node to find any associated areas:

```
node[name="New York"][is_in~"NY"];foreach(out;is_in;out;);
```

To get the relation ID, subtract 3600000000 from the area ID returned by the above queries. Then get the relation from its ID:

```
(relation(" + relationID + ");>;);out;
```

You can test out queries here, mine could probably be improved on:
http://overpass-api.de/query_form.html

That is how to get the city boundaries, processing them is another matter as nothing is in order within the relation. For that see my GitHub project and:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:multipolygon/Algorithm

Also I would note that the OpenStreetMap data for city boundaries is spotty. It is missing for big cities like Dallas and LA from what I can tell.

Comment: Looks like they've added LA since 2013.  Dallas is still missing, but Forth Worth and the rest of the surrounding cities are there.
See: http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/207359