# Spark reading Open Street Map data and selecting entries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, openstreetmap

I have OpenStreetMap (OSM) data from a .orc stored in `var nlorc` of a country for which I am trying to read out data for specific cities. As far as I know, a city entity is defined as a 'relation' in OSM. The `nlorc.printSchema()` of my data returns the following:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- lat: decimal(9,7) (nullable = true)
 |-- lon: decimal(10,7) (nullable = true)
 |-- nds: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ref: long (nullable = true)
 |-- members: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ref: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- role: string (nullable = true)
 |-- changeset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- uid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- version: long (nullable = true)
 |-- visible: boolean (nullable = true)
```

As an example, https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/47798#map=13/51.4373/4.8888 shows that the name of the city is part of "Tags". How can I access the keys of Tags and select specific cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getItem` to access the elements of the map:

```scala
df = ...
df.filter(df("tags").getItem("name")==="Baarle-Nassau").show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you by any chance know how to extract the coordinates of a city's border?

Comment: @gilianzz I am not sure if the coordinates are part of your orc data, but I am not too familiar with OSM data... I think you have to iterate over the `members` array and load more data from the OSM server for each entry. This [php answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502007/2129801) might be helpful.